# Export Excel sheet to PDF got 400 and 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

Please see code below:

```
Sub SmartPDF_Generator()

    Dim answer As Integer

    pdfName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5) & " __ " & Cells(1, 8)        
    answer = MsgBox("Please confirm creat dashboard for Carrier" & Cells(1, 5) & " Event" & Cells(1, 8), vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Comfirm dashboard")

    If answer = vbNo Then        
        MsgBox ("Please select your carrier and event combination again")        
    Else        
        ChDir ("C:\test\")                
        fileSaveName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5) & " __ " & Cells(1, 8)

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        fileSaveName _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

        MsgBox "File Saved " & " " & fileSaveName        
    End If        
Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works for me on a sheet with E1 and H1 populated, but I get error 1004 if they are both blank ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5)` and `Cells(1, 8)` are empty before you let the code continue. and why are you not using `ActiveSheet` on the second condition? without that qualifier, you are just asking for trouble.

Comment: you should be using a well defined sheet object instead of relying on Excel to guess which sheet you are processing. very poor habit